# Is there a way to stack table cells in a row arbitrarily? (for responsive design)

Tags: css, layout, html-table

I'd like a table to be a bit responsive (yes, I know tables "shouldn't be used responsively" but that's where we are right now)

Specifically, the table has 4 small, related cells that need to stack 2x2 if the screen is small enough. I'm able to get the cells to stack with display: block, but that stacks them 4x1. I'd like to be able to selectively apply some kind of style (I suppose to the 2nd (or 2nth) cell) to force it to break.

```
td {
  display: block;
}
```

I'm able to hack it to work with a phantom table cell but that's WAY messier than "using tables in responsive design" since it's adding extraneous elements to the markup.

Is there a better way to achieve the effect in this fiddle without the "nothing" td? http://jsfiddle.net/2rLpme4s/

Comment: Does it have to be a table? You could do this very easily using CSS Grid.

Comment: @Nick legacy code and no time right now to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of weird to do this, but you could effect that pretty easily by setting CSS grid behind a media query to only break the table display under certain conditions. Here, I'm arbitrarily picking 40em. Resize your browser to see the effect, which I've tried to make clear with some additional styles that aren't necessary for the technique:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {  
  tr {
    display: grid;
  }

  td {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
  }

  td.stat {
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  td.stat2 {
    grid-row: 2;
  }

  /* Extra styles just for clarity */
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }

  td {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    outline: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    padding: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>A </td>
    <td>B </td>
    <td>C </td>
    <td class="stat">D </td>
    <td class="stat2">E </td>
    <td class="stat">F </td>
    <td class="stat2">G </td>
    <td>H </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works by setting table data cells to span from the first row to the start of the third (1 / 3), i.e., two rows, and then using the `.stat` and `.stat2` selectors to set each specifically in the first or second row.